# Create a folder from a file name which has 2 underscores, then place that file in the folder

Tags: windows, powershell

I try to  create a folder using PowerShell for the  following files

```
4_2017-07-16_01-22-52.mp4
4_2017-07-16_01-23-50.mp4
4_2017-07-16_01-24-54.mp4
4_2017-07-16_01-26-21.mp4
```

I use this method

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41468253/13002495

the problem that it will create a  directory 4 then move the files to it what I need to have a directory like the following

4_2017-07-16 or a directory like 4_2017_07_16

this is the first method.

the second method if you can help to have a script to create the following directories

2017 directory then a subdirectory 02 then subdirectory 16 then a subdirectory 4 then move the files to subdirectory 4

so it will be as following

```
2017
--------07
------------16
---------------------04 ----> files will be here
```

can you help with these 2 methods?

Comment: Change `_.*` to `.*_` to resolve the first issue.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
$folder = 'FILES_FOLDER'

Get-ChildItem -Path $folder | ForEach-Object {
    $subFolders = $_.Name.Split("-_")
    $path = Get-Location
    $order = 1, 2, 3, 0

    $order | ForEach-Object {
        $path = Join-Path -Path $path -ChildPath $subFolders[$_]

        if (-not (Test-Path -Path $path -PathType Container)){
            New-Item -Path $path -ItemType Directory
        }
    }

    Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $path
}
```

Which will move all files to:

```
2017/07/16/4/4_2017-07-16_01-22-52.mp4
2017/07/16/4/4_2017-07-16_01-23-50.mp4
2017/07/16/4/4_2017-07-16_01-24-54.mp4
2017/07/16/4/4_2017-07-16_01-26-21.mp4
```

**Explanation:**

- Split the files on `"-"` and `"_"` with `Split`. Can look at [`about_split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_split?view=powershell-7) for more information.
- Get the current folder path with [`Get-Location`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-location?view=powershell-7), which is used to append to the current path for making sub directories.
- Create an `$order` array to create the correct sub folder order as shown in the question.
- Iterate through this `$order` array and create new directories if they dont exist. Can use [`Test-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/test-path?view=powershell-7) to check if the sub folders exist, and [`New-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-item?view=powershell-7) to create a new directory.
- Move files to final sub directory with [`Move-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/move-item?view=powershell-7). These sub directories will be in your current working directory. You could obviously change this to another directory location as well.

Answer (score 1):

For your first method (one destination folder with name like `4_2017_07_16`), you can do:

```
$source      = 'D:\Mp4Files'  # rootfolder where the files are
$destination = 'D:\Test'      # rootfolder where the files need to go
Get-ChildItem -Path $source -File -Filter '*.mp4' |
  Group-Object { ($_.BaseName -replace'(\d+_[^_]+).*', '$1') } |
  ForEach-Object {
    $targetFolder = Join-Path -Path $destination -ChildPath $_.Name
    # create this folder if it does not already exist
    if (!(Test-Path -Path $targetFolder -PathType Container)) {
        $null = New-Item -Path $targetFolder -ItemType Directory
    }
    $_.Group | Move-Item -Destination $targetFolder
}
```

Result:

> ```
> D:\TEST\4_2017-07-16
>     4_2017-07-16_01-22-52.mp4
>     4_2017-07-16_01-23-50.mp4
>     4_2017-07-16_01-24-54.mp4
>     4_2017-07-16_01-26-21.mp4
> ```

The second method creates more subfolders, based on the first part of the filenames:

```
$source      = 'D:\Mp4Files'
$destination = 'D:\Test'
Get-ChildItem -Path $source -File -Filter '*.mp4' |
  Group-Object { ($_.BaseName -replace'(\d+_[^_]+).*', '$1') } |
  ForEach-Object {
    $index, $year, $month, $day = $_.Name -split '[-_]'
    $targetFolder = Join-Path -Path $destination -ChildPath ('{0}\{1:00}\{2:00}\{3:00}' -f $year, [int]$month, [int]$day, [int]$index)
    # create this folder if it does not already exist
    if (!(Test-Path -Path $targetFolder -PathType Container)) {
        $null = New-Item -Path $targetFolder -ItemType Directory
    }
    $_.Group | Move-Item -Destination $targetFolder
}
```

Result:

> ```
> D:\TEST\2017
> \---07
>     \---16
>         \---04
>                 4_2017-07-16_01-22-52.mp4
>                 4_2017-07-16_01-23-50.mp4
>                 4_2017-07-16_01-24-54.mp4
>                 4_2017-07-16_01-26-21.mp4
> ```